# Объединение массива

Tags: php, sql

существует вывод данных из базы, необходимо объединить все данные из массивов и вывести полученный массив только с уникальными значениями

```
Array ( [0] => 83 ) Array ( [0] => 85 )
Array ( [0] => 77 ) Array ( [0] => 85 )
Array ( [0] => 83 ) Array ( [0] => 85 )Array ( [0] => 55 ) Array ( [0] => 99 )
```

выглядит вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    $sql222 ="select DISTINCT number_cont from  ".$new_array[$i]."";
    $result222 = mysqli_query($con, $sql222);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result222) > 0)
    {
        echo '<table>';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result222))
        {
            $re=array_merge((array)$row["number_cont"]);
            print_r($re);
        }          
        echo '</table>';
    }
```

В PHP вообще не силен, поэтому прошу помощи

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score -2):

Не до конца понял как у вас получились дубли после `DISTINCT`, возможно дело в продолжении запроса. Можно сделать что-то вроде примера ниже, если Вам надо именно это.

```
$sql222 ="select DISTINCT number_cont from ".$new_array[$i];
$result222 = mysqli_query($con, $sql222);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result222) > 0)
{
    echo '<table>';
    $re = [];
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result222))
        $re[] = $row["number_cont"];
    $uniques = array_unique($re);
    foreach($uniques as $item)
        print_r($item);
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Или по ключам (автоматически перезапишет копию):

```
$sql222 ="select DISTINCT number_cont from ".$new_array[$i];
$result222 = mysqli_query($con, $sql222);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result222) > 0)
{
    echo '<table>';
    $re = [];
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result222))
        $re[$row["number_cont"]] = $row["number_cont"];

    foreach($re as $key=>$item)
        print_r($key);
    echo '</table>';
}
```